# Scroll the people list in Facebook, bringing the scrollbar down to the end. My code not working correctly. How can I solve?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrollbar

I would like to scroll down, up to the maximum end of the scroll (up to the last person's name), the list of people who have left a like on Facebook (in the "All" section). The link, for example from a New York Time post, is this: https://www.facebook.com/nytimestravel/photos/a.142272672496512/5176942835696112/ (maybe to view you have to log in with your facebook, I don't know)

I am using this code, but it is not working:

```
#code for access to facebook with driver in firefox
#(i avoid writing so as not to stretch and be more synthetic)
# ....

#scrollbar
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]')
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

[image]

I'm not getting any errors, but the problem is, using this code, nothing happens. The vertical scrollbar does not move and the list does not scroll down

I've tried using several xpatches, but they don't work. I am using this code. I don't know if I'm wrong to enter the xpatch or if the whole code is wrong. Can anyone help me? Thanks

UPDATE
For additional information, use this class to open the browser and simulate with Firefox (obviously this is just a part of the code. I don't insert it all to keep the question concise)

```
class Facebook:
    #Access Facebook
    #/usr/bin/firefox/firefox
    profile_path = '....'

    options=Options()
    options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
    options.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 4)
    options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
    options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
    options.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)
    #options.set_preference("network.cookie.cookieBehavior", 0) #http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.cookie.cookieBehavior

    service = Service('/home/xxxx/bin/geckodriver')
    global driver
    driver = Firefox(service=service, options=options)
    driver.set_window_size(600, 990)
    driver.set_window_position(1, 1)
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com")

    #Cookie prima del login
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-cookiebanner="accept_button"]'))).click()

    #Login
    username_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'email')
    username_box.send_keys(email.get())
    password_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'pass')
    password_box.send_keys(password.get())

    #Open link
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/button'))).click()

    #Click on icon-blu like
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='j1lvzwm4']"))).click()

    #Click on All
    WebDriverWait(driver, 200).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]'))).click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the propmt for `reaction` opens (`in div`), you can use the below xPath

```
//div[@data-visualcompletion='ignore-dynamic' and not(@role) and not(@class)]
```

This will target each and every row in that prompt.

**Code:**

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")

#try:
    #Cookie prima del login
    #WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-cookiebanner="accept_button"]'))).click()
#except:
    #pass

#Login
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "email"))).send_keys('user id here')
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "pass"))).send_keys('password here')

#Click on login
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[name='login']"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/nytimestravel/photos/a.142272672496512/5176942835696112/")

time.sleep(2)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@aria-label='See who reacted to this']"))).click() #this is to click on like, and reaction button
time.sleep(4)
# Click on All
WebDriverWait(driver, 200).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]'))).click()

i = 1
while True:
    try:
        row = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"(// div[@ data-visualcompletion='ignore-dynamic' and not ( @ role) and not (@class )])[{i}]")))
        time.sleep(0.5)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", row)
        i = i + 1
    except:
        print('Scrolled all the element, and must have not found the index hence break from the loop')
        break
```

Comment: I tried your code,but it doesn't work.I print text "Scrolled all the element...". The names do not flow.I don't know if it matters,but before opening your code I use WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='j1lvzwm4']"))).click() to click on the blue like logo, then use WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]'))).click() to click ALL. Right after that,I use your code,but your code doesn't scroll

Comment: PART 2: I HAVE UPDATED THE APPLICATION CODE, but only for information purposes. Maybe with more information you can help me better. Thanks

Comment: Are you able to click on `reaction` button and then `all`? I have written the code for that as well. See the update section above. After these line of code, you can write scroll code. That should help you.

Comment: Yes, previously I was able to click on reaction and then on All (I updated the code, writing what I use to do these two things). My code for Reaction and All was already working correctly. Thanks all the same for your suggestion, you are kind :) The problem though is your code for scrolling the vertical scrollbar all the way down. Your code is not working. The list of people does not automatically go down. Can you check your code for scrolling the scrollbar? Thanks

Comment: @Jas_99: I made some changes in the existing script (see above updated code), I have tested this code on chrome and firefox, and it is working just fine.